# VBA Rows.Count in Selection

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to work out how many rows a user has selected to be displayed at the top of the sheet next to an action button, I.e. Button says "Generate Email" and next to it says "x items selected".

As this is updated everytime the selection is changed, I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Sheet1.Range("E1") = Target.Rows.Count & " items selected"
End Sub
```

This works fine if the user selects consecutive rows, for e.g. 7:10 returns 4.

My problem is if a user selected rows 7, and 10. It would only return 1 (the rows in the first part of the selection).

From what I've found, there is no way of just getting this value from a property, but I can't get my head around how to iterate through all parts of the selection/target and calculate the sum of rows. Then there is also the possibility that the user selects say A7, C7, and A10. A7 and C7 relate to the same item, so this should only really be treated as one, not two, which I think my hypothetical code would do...

Has anyone tried to achieve this before and been successful or could point me in the direction of some properties which may help? I tried a separate function to achieve it, but that wasn't working either.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Sheet1.Range("E1") = getRowCount(Target) & " items selected"
End Sub

Function getRowCount(selectedRanges As Ranges)
  rowCount = 0
  For Each subRange In selectedRanges
    rowCount = rowCount + subRange.Rows.Count
  Next

  getRowCount = rowCount
End Function
```

Comment: Esperadoce - thanks for the edit to format, I just downloaded the app in the hope of adding the formatting but you beat me to it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work.  (Did when I tried it.)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Create a range containing just column A
    Dim subRange As Range
    Dim r As Range
    For Each subRange In Target.Areas
        If r Is Nothing Then
            Set r = subRange.EntireRow.Columns(1)
        Else
            Set r = Union(r, subRange.EntireRow.Columns(1))
        End If
    Next
    'Count how many cells in the combined column A range
    Sheet1.Range("E1") = r.Cells.Count & " items selected"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, as it's the first one I've integrated and it's worked straight away. It's not in a way I would have ever come up with, but it makes sense to me as an easy way to perform the calculation. This next bit wasn't part of my original question, but moving forwards, is there a way to iterate through r(?) to get data from various columns in each row?

Comment: @OliBarton In my code, `r` has absolutely nothing to do with the original selection other than that it is referring to column A on each of the rows.  So if your selection had been `B5:B10,D8:D12,C15:J20` then `r` would be `A5:A12,A15:A20`.  So if you were after `D5:D12,D15:D20` you could iterate through each cell in `r` and use an `Offset(0, 3)` to get to the corresponding column D (or just iterate through `r.EntireRow.Coumns("D")`), but if you were only interested in `D8:D12,D15:D20` you would need to iterate through `Intersect(r.EntireRow.Columns("D"), Target)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to count the rows in each `Area` the user has selected.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-areas-property-excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rArea As Range
    Dim lCount As Long

    For Each rArea In Selection.Areas
        lCount = lCount + rArea.Rows.Count
    Next rArea

    Sheet1.Range("E1") = lCount

End Sub
```

Comment: You beat me by about 20 seconds! :D  (P.S.  Any suggestion as to how to avoid double-counting rows if they occur in multiple areas?  May not be an issue in the OP's scenario but, if you have any bright ideas, it would still be good to know for future reference.)

Comment: I hadn't considered the double-counting until I read your first comment.  Thinking about it now.

Comment: And, on re-reading the question, it sounds like it **does** occur in the OP's scenario :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had stumbled upon the .Areas but for some reason I couldn't get it to work (I didn't comment it out like I normally do so no idea what I did), but this does work, sort of. As you've already identified in the comments, it doesn't take into account the duplicates :(

Comment: I did start working on one that would take into account duplicates, but the answers given by both YowE3K and SixthSense appear to work so I stopped.  I haven't tried the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub NumberOfRowsSelected()
Dim vMatch As Variant, aRows() As Long, r As Range, x As Long

ReDim Preserve aRows(x)
aRows(x) = 0

For Each r In Selection.Cells
    vMatch = Application.Match(r.Row, aRows, 0)

    If IsError(vMatch) Then
        x = x + 1
        ReDim Preserve aRows(0 To x)
        aRows(x) = r.Row
    End If
Next r

MsgBox UBound(aRows)

End Sub
```

**Revised Code Converted as Function**

```
Sub NumberOfRowsSelected()
    MsgBox RowsCount(Selection)
End Sub

Function RowsCount(rRange As Range) As Long
Dim vMatch As Variant, aRows() As Long, r As Range, x As Long

ReDim Preserve aRows(x)
aRows(x) = 0

For Each r In rRange.Cells
    vMatch = Application.Match(r.Row, aRows, 0)

    If IsError(vMatch) Then
        x = x + 1
        ReDim Preserve aRows(0 To x)
        aRows(x) = r.Row
    End If
Next r

RowsCount = UBound(aRows)

End Function
```

Comment: Your set up of `aRows` confuses me, you `ReDim` it to size 0 using `x` which isn't defined (why not just `Dim` it to the right size anyway?) and then assign the 0th element the value 0, which it already has by default anyway... Also if this was a function then it would be more useful, returning the value rather than invoking the devil (`MsgBox`)

Comment: By default Array starts with Zero Counter.  I am starting array with zero counter since x is also zero and i have not assigned any value to x so x is zero by default.  aRows(x) in this it means that aRows(0).  In excel rows starts with 1 and there is no 0 row in excel.  So aRows(x) = 0 means that I am saying aRows(0_Counter) = 0 as row value to set the aRows variable as array.  So that  Match function will consider it as array and will not throw any error since I have loaded a 0 Row value in the aRows array.

Comment: Ah okay, consider adding a few comments to your future answers to illustrate points like this which aren't immediately obvious to readers :) thanks

Comment: Okay, I will try to do that in my future posts :)

Answer (score 1):

A different method, building up a string of checked rows seems pretty straight-forward to avoid double counting. See comments for details:

```
Function getRowCount(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim c As Range
    ' Keep track of which rows we've already counted
    Dim countedrows As String: countedrows = ","
    ' Loop over cells in range
    For Each c In rng
        ' Check if already counted
        If Not InStr(countedrows, "," & c.Row & ",") > 0 Then
            ' Add to counted list
            countedrows = countedrows & c.Row & ","
        End If
    Next c
    ' Get number of rows counted
    Dim rowsarr() As String: rowsarr = Split(countedrows, ",")
    getRowCount = UBound(rowsarr) - LBound(rowsarr) - 1
End Function
```

Comment: Would it be a problem, if we have for example `13,` then would `3,` count? I had exact same idea after your remark :)

Comment: You're right, I only accounted for the `1,` and `13,` case! I've edited my answer to ensure there is a comma both sides of every number, should work now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was confident this would work when reading through it, but I've put it into my workbook and annoyingly it's counting duplicate rows =/ Just to check, should I simply call it as follows: Dim lCount As Long --and then-- lCount = getRowCount(Selection) ?

Comment: You're right, something odd is happening here, I've posted a question about it myself! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636183/strange-cell-addresses-behaviour-for-non-contiguous-ranges

Comment: @OliBarton I have fixed my code, still see my above linked question in pursuit of the weird behaviour, but the code above works with not counting duplicate rows now (and it even got a touch simpler)!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range
Dim i, currentRow As Long: i = 0
'get row of first cell in range
currentRow = Target.Cells(1, 1).row

For Each cell In Target
    'if row is different, then increase number of items, as it's next item
    If Not currentRow = cell.row Then
       i = i + 1
       currentRow = cell.row
    End If
Next cell

Range("E1").Value = i

End Sub
```

Comment: You could select out of order, then the next cell is not necessarily lower than the previous cell