# Strange cell addresses behaviour for non-contiguous ranges: VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I was trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45632012/vba-rows-count-in-selection) when I came across some bizarre VBA behaviour in Excel. I have written a very simple sub to demonstrate the issue:

```
Sub debugAddresses(rng As Range)
    Debug.Print "Whole range: " & rng.Address
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
        Debug.Print rng.Cells(i).Address
    Next i
End Sub
```

I loop over each cell in a range object and print its address, simple right?

```
debugAddresses Range("B2:B3")  
' Result as expected: 
' >> Whole range: $B$2:$B$3
' >> $B$2
' >> $B$3
```

However, for non-contiguous ranges I get some strange behaviour:

```
debugAddresses Range("A1,B2")
' Strange behaviour when getting addresses of individual cells:
' >> Whole range: $A$1,$B$2
' >> $A$1
' >> $A$2
```

Can anyone shed any light on this please? Specifically **why** the `Cells` objects, which can be used for indexing of a contiguous range, seem to just extend the first selected `Area`.

---

Edit: It might be worth noting that using a `For Each` loop through the actual cell range objects gives the expected result*

```
Sub debugAddresses2(rng As Range)
    Debug.Print "Whole range: " & rng.Address
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rng
        Debug.Print c.Address
    Next c
End Sub
```

*<sup>See my answer for a comment on a more robust solution, as this (apparently) may not *always* give the expected result</sup>

Comment: You are using non-contiguous ranges, so `rng.Cells(i).Address` is likely a shorthand for `rng.Areas(1).Cells(i).Address`.

Comment: It is strange, because if you try to input some data on those cells. It actually work: rng.Cells = "test"

Comment: @FlorentB. "is likely shorthand" based on what? Got any docs on that? Also I don't think so, because there aren't enough cells in `.Areas(1)` and you'd get index out of range...

Comment: @Wolfie, because it would match exactly the behavior you are describing. Moreover, `Cells(i)` is not bounded to the original range: `Range("A1:A3").Cells(100, 1)`.

Comment: @Wolfie, try to think on how you would implement it internally and you'll see it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @FlorentB. I didn't trust the "think how I'd do it" strategy - the VBA compiler would not be improved with my lowly input ;) However, I had a hunt through the object structure, the results of which you can see in my own answer below. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Florent's comment was in the correct direction, and that this method is extending the first `Area` within the range object.

In a contiguous range (e.g. `"A1:B5"`, `"C10:C100"`) the following method loops over each cell in the given range, `rng`.

```
Dim j As Long
For j = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
    Debug.Print rng.Cells(j).Address
Next j
```

However, in non-contiguous ranges it appears that this is equivalent (or *shorthand for*)

```
For j = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
    Debug.Print rng.Areas(1).Cells(j).Address
Next j
```

---

There doesn't appear to be any direct mention of this in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-cells-property-excel) but it is a sensible conclusion to draw by looking in the Locals browser of the VBA editor.

In the range object `rng`, there is a `Cells` property which only contains one "Item", which is the first `Area`. So it's reasonable to assume this one item is what `.Cells(j)` has access to.

[image: cells]

In `rng` we can also see the `Areas` property, which contains 2 items (in this example) equal to the number of `Areas` in my non-contiguous range.

[image: areas]

---

So `rng.Cells(j)` is accessing the `j`th element within the first area of `rng`. Because `.Cells()` can extend past the original size of `rng`, we see the addresses listed of cells outside `rng`.

---

The solution(s):

- Either ensure you directly loop through the range objects within `rng` using a `For Each` loop as shown in the question.
- Or loop over each area, and then each cell within that area.

The first option is more concise, but Shai points out that to be completely sure, the most robust method is to do the two `For Each` loops as there may be more complicated edge cases which aren't captured with the single loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the modified `Sub debugAddresses` code below:

```
Sub debugAddresses(rng As Range)

    Dim RngA As Range
    Dim C As Range

    For Each RngA In rng.Areas
        For Each C In RngA.Cells
            Debug.Print C.Address
        Next C
    Next RngA

End Sub
```

Comment: So this works, but do you know *why* the original didn't work? Even in distinct areas the addresses shouldn't change surely? It's not like the cells are all `$A$1` within their own areas...

Comment: Also see my edit, an even simpler `For Each` loop works, just not cell indexing...

Comment: @Wolfie  regarding your first question, I always double For Each loop, one through area, and the other for Cells.

Comment: Is that just habit or is there a reason? For instance do you know of an example when using one `For Each` (as I do in my question at the end) would fail?

Comment: @Wolfie yes, just had one last month, but I can't remember right now...

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code **"fixed"**. by just adding one more For Loop

```
Sub debugAddresses(rng As Range)

    Debug.Print "Whole range: " & rng.Address

    For Each r In rng ' this loops through the range even if separated cells

    Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To r.Cells.Count 'changed to r instead of rng
            Debug.Print r.Cells(i).Address 'changed to r instead of rng
        Next i
    Next r

End Sub
```

So `.Range` works by entering the cell address ex. `"B1"`, or by using `R1C1` meaning row column ex. 1,2.

But you cant use just one `R1C1` inside of .Range, since the range here is a span of cells. So to properly use `R1C1` in `.Range`, you have to specify 2 of them.

So `.Range("B5:B10")` is equal to `Range(Cells(5,2),Cells(10,2))`

What you did was Specify a Range, then from that created another range using Cells. Very much like **offset**.

So `Range("A1,B2")` then adding `Cells(1)` then `Cells(2)` adds rows to the first range that is "A1" or offsets.

```
Sub selector()
Set Rng = Range("A1")
Rng.Select
Rng.Cells(4, 4).Select

End Sub
```

This offsets 4 colums and 4 rows from A1

Comment: I don't think you're quite right, it's perfectly valid to specify a range how I have done, with just one range address and a comma within it, nothing to do with R1C1. You can see this in the first debug statement which shows the range address is as desired. What you've done in the code block is just replicate a part of the problem for an individual cell, when I'm specifically looping within the number of cells *contained by* `rng`.

Comment: Im not arguing its validity, Im arguing its proper use. You have used `.Cells` on `.Range` and expect it to stay within `.Range`? Then why not just use `.Range` by itself OR `.Cells`? why use them both? `.Range.Cell` acts like an offset. To loop through your cells in range, use For Each r in Range

Comment: Within a contiguous block, `.Range.Cells` acts like an indexing tool, where yes you can reliably loop up to the number of cells in the range object and expect to stay within the range. This is why my question is specifically about why this behaviour happens in non-contiguous ranges, i.e. the structure which VBA uses to access `Cells` objects within a range. In my question I show that I know I can use `For Each`.

Comment: Your fixed code is the same as (but longer than) the last code in my question. Thanks for offering your time, I was after the *why* not the *please fix my code* though

Comment: Within a **contiguous** block, .Range.Cells acts like an indexing tool. emphasis on contigious. meaning touching borders, beside each other. `debugAddresses Range("A1,B2")` this is not contiguous, its now being treated as a collection of ranges instead of 1 whole range. thats why you need to loop through them.

Comment: from the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel
`If you work with selections that contain more than one area, the Areas property is useful. It divides a multiple-area selection into individual Range objects and then returns the objects as a collection. You can use the Count property on the returned collection to verify a selection that contains more than one area, as shown in the following example.` Proving my point that non-contiguous is a collection that you need to loop over.

Comment: Its in the docs, the problem I believe lies in your pre-conception on how it "should work".

Comment: I think it's less of a preconception of "how it should work" and more "how it does work in other cases which I'm more familiar with". I am happy with the concept of looping over areas, and a non-contig. range will have multiple areas. I didn't previously have any experience with how the `Range(...).Cells(i)` command interacted with those ranges, which is not documented clearly. If your docs quote had said "When using `Cells` to access a range with multiple areas, this is the behaviour..." then I would have been happy :)

Comment: my problem would be why it allowed to run on the collection in the first place. why it automatically allowed access to the first item without looping it over first.

Comment: Ah I sense we're in agreement at last: VBA has some stupid quirks! Thanks for the discussion

Comment: but learning vba made it easier to learn python, so i hold it close to my heart haha.