# VBA: look for particular values in multiple non-adjacent columns

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have some code that looks through a range (currently only in column A) for particular values, takes that value and looks up a sheet in another book with the value name. It also sets the value address as a variable 'WhereCell' that i use in another part of the code. The code as it is works perfectly.

I now want to change the code so it looks for values in both column A, and two other columns (possibly N and Y but that may change). how can i do this? I've put my code as it is below, but i get error 13: type mismatch on the line `dem1 = .Range("A" & x, "N" & x).Value`, I assume because i cant put the "A" and "N" in the same range statement. How can i change it to search through multiple columns?

```
 Sub GetFlows()

Dim cell As Range
Dim dem1 As String
Dim WhereCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim valueRng As Range
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Name <> "Summary" Then
            For x = 9 To 200 ' run a loop from row 9 to 200
                dem1 = .Range("A" & x, "N" & x).Value
                MsgBox dem1

                If dem1 <> "" Then
                    Set WhereCell = .Range("A9:A200").Find(what:=dem1, LookAt:=xlPart)

                    If Not WhereCell Is Nothing Then
                        Workbooks("GetFilenames v2.xlsm").Worksheets(dem1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
                        WhereCell.Offset(, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    End If
                End If
            Next x
        End If
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

EDIT: i've solved it, I just repeated the entire code between 'For x' and 'next x' and changed the variables to refer to column N:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Name <> "Summary" Then
            For x = 9 To 200 ' run a loop from row 9 to 200
                dem1 = .Range("A" & x).Value

                If dem1 <> "" Then
                    Set WhereCell_1 = .Range("A9:A200").Find(what:=dem1, LookAt:=xlPart)

                    If Not WhereCell_1 Is Nothing Then
                        Workbooks("GetFilenames v3.xlsm").Worksheets(dem1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
                        WhereCell_1.Offset(, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    End If
                End If
            Next x

            For y = 9 To 200 ' run a loop from row 9 to 200
                dem2 = .Range("N" & y).Value

                If dem2 <> "" Then
                    Set WhereCell_2 = .Range("N9:N200").Find(what:=dem2, LookAt:=xlPart)

                    If Not WhereCell_2 Is Nothing Then
                        Workbooks("GetFilenames v3.xlsm").Worksheets(dem2).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
                        WhereCell_2.Offset(, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    End If
                End If
            Next y
        End If
    End With
Next ws
```

That works fine, but i wonder if there is a way to avoid repeating the code and do it in a cleaner, more compact way.

Comment: `what:=dem1` is the value you are searching for, so to change the Range of search, you have to change this part `.Range("A9:A200")` and not the what value. For more information read [.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)

Comment: What does `dem1` have to do with the name of a worksheet in `Worksheets(dem1)`? What are you actually looking for?

Comment: @Jeeped dem1 is what the values in column A and others will be (different each time, an example is '2016_6500_DM_PM.txt'), then it will look these values up in another workbook where the dem1 values are the sheet names. On each sheet is some data that i get and put back in thisworkbook.

Comment: @RichPrag Note that you could make it all on the same function, creating a [non contiguous range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636183/strange-cell-addresses-behaviour-for-non-contiguous-ranges-vba). And looping through it.